# Composite primary key consisting of primay keys from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am working on an assignment and I'm a little rusty with my SQL basics as I mainly work with already created tables, not with creating them. I was given a database model and asked to create it. I was told the model may have errors and to just correct them. Here is a snippet of the part I am having issue with:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPflb.jpg

I've been trying to figure it out and Googling and researching but I'm just not sure if there's something I'm not getting or I need to adjust the model. The issue I am having is with the `operation` table and the connecting tables. The primary key for `operation` is made up of the three primary keys from the connecting tables and another primary key, `date`. Can that be done? If they were foreign keys in the other tables I think I could figure it out. I've been trying to figure out how to do it but mostly just trying to wrap my head around the concept of what this is showing. I just don't understand how or why. Wouldn't that composite primary key have to be in the other 3 tables are they fine split up? Shouldn't that composite primary key be referencing foreign keys in other tables? I'm just really confused. I'm ok working with databases but designing, not so much.

I would just ask my professor about it but we are never on the same page. I think I understand him in the moment and then I wind up more confused. I don't think it matters for this but it's MySQL.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: I've just never seen a composite primary key reference primary keys in another table. Is that a mistake in the model? I tried to figure out how to do it but can't get it. I can't even really get my head around the concept.

Comment: The model looks fine regarding `operation`, each record there exists only as a combination of the keys of the 3 related tables plus the date. So they are foreign keys, but together they are a composite primary key.  The only flaw would be if the same operation name can be performed multiple times by the same doctor on the same patient on the same date, but guessing that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, I now understand my misconception. I was thinking the primary composite key is made up of primary keys, duplicates from the other tables. I realize now that the composite primary key is made up of *foreign* keys and one primary key: date. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is technically allowable, I think that it is semantically meaningless in this case as it allows the following situation to exist.

1. A patient can be subject to the same operation on the same day multiple times by different doctors, but ...
2. the patient cannot be subject to the same operation on the same day multiple times by the same doctor, but ...
3. the patient can be subject to different operations from the same doctor on the same day.

To me, this primary key is nonsense and you might as well add a synthetic primary key and make these simple foreign key columns where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with declaring a composite PK where some of the components are also declared FKs.  Logically, this is quite correct.

The effects on performance will be hard to predict.  The index that Mysql builds based on the PK declaration will be hard to predict.  Some queries will be sped up, others won't.

Comment: But the components aren't foreign keys, they are primary keys in another table. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: If the values all refer to some PK then they are an FK, by definition.  There is some confusion on this score.  Many contributors refer to a column as an FK only if it is named in an FK constraint.

Comment: Well, then what are the primary keys for the tables `doctor`, `patient, and `operation type`? I kind of thought that was the case. I just can't make sense of the model. I was told to just fix any mistakes in it but I don't have enough database design experience to understand the intention in the model and fix it.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand. The composite primary key in `operation` is composed of foreign keys, right? I was thinking it backwards. It was a conceptualization issue for me. Thanks, I think I understand now.